# How to update data across pages when using Nextjs <Link>

Tags: reactjs, next.js, trpc

I am using nextjs (pages dir), trpc, and prisma. I have 5 pages where there is overlap in terms of data that is queried on each but I'm utilizing different trpc endpoints because of  varying structure & different data  required depending on the page. These pages have no relation to each other outside being linked in a navigation menu that uses the Nextjs `<Link>`.

**The problem I am facing is when a user updates data on one page, it refetches the updated data fine for that page, but when they navigate to the other page, the change is not reflected unless I refresh.** I'm assuming the reason is `<Link>` pre-fetched the data before the change. Obv when I just use a regular `<a>` I don't get this problem, but it becomes much slower to navigate. How can I fix this issue without having to resort back to the `<a>`?

I tried using the ctx.[tableName].[endpoint].invalidate() when a mutation is made, but that isn't working. Also having a shared context with all the data seems like it would present new issues.

Here are some examples of my api calls. Both calls are pulling data that has substantial overlap but also has differences:

[sceneId].tsx page:

```
const { data: allScenesForProject } = api.scene.getByProjectIdElements.useQuery({ projectId: projectId }, { enabled: !!projectId });
```

scheduleboard.tsx page:

```
const { data: projectData } = api.project.getById.useQuery({ id: projectId }, { enabled: !!projectId });
```

**Update:** one thing I forgot to mention is each page has it's own context for all the children components that live under each one. I'm assuming here it has something to do with the context keeping stale data.

Comment: Have you tried adding <Link prefetch={false} />?

Comment: @ArnasDičkus yes I have tried prefetch={false} and I still get the same issue I would  when it defaults to true